# Why p,d and f orbitals have non spherical shapes

Tags: quantum-chemistry, orbitals

I know what orbitals are. The orbitals are solutions (also called wave functions) to the (time-independent) Schrödinger equation[[ref]](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/14258/139).

What I don't understand is why p,d,f orbitals have non spherical and s has a spherical shape. Our universe is made up of many circular or spherically (not perfect)  shaped objects like stars, planets, bubbles, droplets, wheels etc. I always thought (or guessed) circular and spherical shapes are the most efficient shapes in our universe. Then why p,d and f have non-spherical shapes or non efficient? Is there any other logic other than solution to Schrodinger equation which explains these unique shapes?

[image]

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14247/why-do-atomic-orbitals-have-their-unique-shapes http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/39987/please-explain-the-shapes-of-the-orbitals

Comment: A separate answer would be that the Laplace functions are a complete basis set, and a set of spherically-symmetric functions can not be a complete basis set.

Comment: There is no such thing as efficient shape.